# Как изменить родительский layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Фрагмент и активити имеют свои собственные layout. Мне нужно изменить layout активити, если я загружаю фрагмент. Например: есть у меня активити с кнопкой А, которая что-то делает. Я нажимаю на кнопку Б, которая вызывает фрагмент (фрагмент динамической реализации), и кнопка А заменяется кнопкой С (кнопка А исчезает, кнопка С появляется). Как я могу добавить кнопку С в layout активити через код фрагмента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверный подход, в разметке активити должны быть только элементы которые должны быть при любых фрагментах. Все остальные элементы должны быть в разметке тех фрагментов для которых они нужны.

В вашем случае видимо кнопка А должна быть на первоначальном фрагменте, который при нажатии кнопки Б будет заменен на фрагмент с кнопкой С.

Comment: Дизайн построен таким образом, что одна кнопка должна выполнять сразу два действия в различных условиях. Если фрагмент прикреплен, то кнопка должна выполнить код, относящийся к фрагменту, иначе - прикрепить этот фрагмент к активити.

Comment: Ну так тогда это одна кнопка и никакой замены нет, в чем тогда проблема?